# Launch JavaFx application from Swing JApplet class

Tags: multithreading, swing, javafx, runnable, japplet

I have to launch a JavaFx application on a click of a JMenuItem of a tree node which extends JApplet class and runs on Swing JFrame window.

I had gone through the tutorials on JavaFx in Swing applications 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm and this question [Run javafx and swing application at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816859/run-javafx-and-swing-application-at-the-same-time) and understood that I have to work JavaFx data on JavaFx application thread.

So I tired to launch the JavaFx application through Platorm.runlater thread on the click of the JMenuItem and made sure that the JavaFx application implements Runnable interface but still I encountered this error : [ToolKit not initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qekew.png).

Here is the sample code of JMenuItem that launches JavaFx Application

```
    static class OpenJavaFxApp extends JMenuItem{
    OpenJavaFxApp(){   
       super("JavaFx App");
        // This should launch JavaFx app
       this.addActionListner(actionEvent -> Platform.runLater(() ->{
                try{
                     // JavaFx app extends Application and 
                     //impelents Runnable 
                     JavaFxApp app = new JavaFxApp;
                     Stage anotherstage = new Stage();
                     app.start(anotherstage);
                     } catch(Exception e){
                         e.printstacktrace();
                         }
                   })
             );
         }
     }
```

Sample JavaFx app code

```
     public class JavaFxApp extends Application implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage){
          AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
          pane.getChildren().addall(AddSomething);
          Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
          primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(Strings[] args){
              launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
             launch();
        }
      }
```

Please be a little bit specific with your solution but any help is appreciated.  Thanks:)

Comment: Applets are obsolescent and will be deprecated in Java 9. Even now most browsers have already removed support for applets. Find a new approach to launch the Java FX desktop app.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys, but I solved it by myself. @mm

Comment: @MMAdams I did use a similar approach of instantiating JFXPanel but not in EDT.